# one drive Redirect url not allowing query string parameters

Tags: onedrive

Currently, I'm trying to integrate the OneDrive SDK onto a website. However, I'm having issue with redirecting with authentication.

Normal route:

- User goes to the website. It clicks on a button to single sign onto there OneDrive
- User gets redirected to OneDrive Authorization page.
- Once authentication, user gets redirected to where they left off. This redirect is specified in the OneDrive's SDK account. However, it seems that they don't allow query params in the redirect URL.

Is there a way around this?

The only thing I could figure out is using a URL that is an alias for the URL with the query params, but that just seems like a hack solution. It's hard to believe that there isn't a way for a user to redirect with query params to indicate at what stage they left off on the site.

Example of invalid redirect url as http://skydpk.com/index.php?a=ap&addon=file_sharing&page=skydrive

Any advice appreciated, Thanks, D

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra parameters through the state parameter of the /authorize request.  Onedrive/Skydrive will pass back the state parameter in the last redirect to you.

So if the redirect url is

> http: //skydpk.com/index.php

then your first OAuth leg looks like this:

> https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPES&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fskydpk.com%2Findex.php&state=state=a%3Dap%26addon%3Dfile_sharing%26page%3Dskydrive

The last OAuth leg then looks like this:

> http://skydpk.com/index.php?code=AUTH_CODE&state=a%3Dap%26addon%3Dfile_sharing%26page%3Dskydrive